# Azure VM cloud-init overrides /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud-init

I added an additional data disk, as described in the [Attach a data disk to a Linux VM documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal).

The partition in question is `/dev/sdc1`. I added this line to the very bottom. Unfortunately the cloud-init magic works its wonders in a bad way and moves around the entries in /etc/fstab and I end up with a "hidden" mount point.

```bsh
root@qwerz:/mnt/builds/docker# cat /etc/fstab
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
UUID=cfadafca-7199-49b1-a353-072629b7fcdf       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
LABEL=UEFI      /boot/efi       vfat    defaults,discard        0 0
UUID=0195f789-b5fa-4bea-a91d-dc120bafb23a       /mnt/builds             ext4    defaults,nofail   1   2
#/dev/sdc1      /mnt/builds     ext4    default,nofail  0       0
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
root@qwerz:/mnt/builds/docker#
```

question 1: should I just move my custom point outside of /mnt?
question 2: what's the cloud-init stuff doing anyway and can I get rid of it?

```bsh
root@qwerz:/mnt/builds/docker# dpkg -l |grep cloud-init
ii  cloud-init                          19.1-1-gbaa47854-0ubuntu1~18.04.1           all          Init scripts for cloud instances
ii  cloud-initramfs-copymods            0.40ubuntu1.1                               all          copy initramfs modules into root filesystem for later use
ii  cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf         0.40ubuntu1.1                               all          write a network interface file in /run for BOOTIF
```

From what I understand cloud-init should only run on the very first time the VM boots. However I have the feeling it also runs after every **deallocation** of any given VM (to save some credits).

The interesting part of cloud-init.log looks like that

```bsh
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/fstab (quiet=False)
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 451 bytes from /etc/fstab
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of ephemeral0
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Mapped metadata name ephemeral0 to /dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed default device ephemeral0 => /dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of swap
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed default device swap => None
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Ignoring nonexistent default named mount swap
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: no need to setup swap
2019-06-26 06:01:49,392 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/mounts (quiet=False)
2019-06-26 06:01:49,393 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2608 bytes from /proc/mounts
2019-06-26 06:01:49,393 - util.py[DEBUG]: Fetched {'sysfs': {'fstype': 'sysfs', 'mountpoint': '/sys', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime'}, 'proc': {'fstype': 'proc', 'mountpoint': '/proc', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime'}, 'udev': {'fstype': 'devtmpfs', 'mountpoint': '/dev', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8187860k,nr_inodes=2046965,mode=755'}, 'devpts': {'fstype': 'devpts', 'mountpoint': '/dev/pts', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000'}, 'tmpfs': {'fstype': 'tmpfs', 'mountpoint': '/sys/fs/cgroup', 'opts': 'ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755'}, '/dev/sda1': {'fstype': 'ext4', 'mountpoint': '/', 'opts': 'rw,relatime,discard'}, 'securityfs': {'fstype': 'securityfs', 'mountpoint': '/sys/kernel/security', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime'}, 'cgroup': {'fstype': 'cgroup', 'mountpoint': '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory'}, 'pstore': {'fstype': 'pstore', 'mountpoint': '/sys/fs/pstore', 'opts': 'rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime'}, 'systemd-1': {'fstype': 'autofs', 'mountpoint': '/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc', 'opts': 'rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18816'}, 'mqueue': {'fstype': 'mqueue', 'mountpoint': '/dev/mqueue', 'opts': 'rw,relatime'}, 'debugfs': {'fstype': 'debugfs', 'mountpoint': '/sys/kernel/debug', 'opts': 'rw,relatime'}, 'hugetlbfs': {'fstype': 'hugetlbfs', 'mountpoint': '/dev/hugepages', 'opts': 'rw,relatime,pagesize=2M'}, 'fusectl': {'fstype': 'fusectl', 'mountpoint': '/sys/fs/fuse/connections', 'opts': 'rw,relatime'}, 'configfs': {'fstype': 'configfs', 'mountpoint': '/sys/kernel/config', 'opts': 'rw,relatime'}, '/dev/loop0': {'fstype': 'squashfs', 'mountpoint': '/snap/dotnet-sdk/39', 'opts': 'ro,nodev,relatime'}, '/dev/loop1': {'fstype': 'squashfs', 'mountpoint': '/snap/core/7169', 'opts': 'ro,nodev,relatime'}, '/dev/loop2': {'fstype': 'squashfs', 'mountpoint': '/snap/dotnet-sdk/38', 'opts': 'ro,nodev,relatime'}, '/dev/loop3': {'fstype': 'squashfs', 'mountpoint': '/snap/core/6964', 'opts': 'ro,nodev,relatime'}, '/dev/loop4': {'fstype': 'squashfs', 'mountpoint': '/snap/dotnet-sdk/35', 'opts': 'ro,nodev,relatime'}, '/dev/sda15': {'fstype': 'vfat', 'mountpoint': '/boot/efi', 'opts': 'rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro,discard'}} mounts from proc
2019-06-26 06:01:49,393 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /etc/fstab - wb: [644] 451 bytes
2019-06-26 06:01:49,393 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: No changes to /etc/fstab made.
2019-06-26 06:01:49,393 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['mount', '-a'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2019-06-26 06:01:49,427 - cc_mounts.py[WARNING]: Activate mounts: FAIL:mount -a
2019-06-26 06:01:49,427 - util.py[WARNING]: Activate mounts: FAIL:mount -a
2019-06-26 06:01:49,427 - util.py[DEBUG]: Activate mounts: FAIL:mount -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_mounts.py", line 495, in handle
    util.subp(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2069, in subp
    cmd=args)
cloudinit.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['mount', '-a']
Exit code: 64
Reason: -
Stdout: 
Stderr: mount: /mnt/builds: mount point does not exist.
```

the mount point of course exists, but not in the previously mounted ephemeral0 temporary storage disk mounted at /mnt :(

Why would you mount a temporary disk under `/mnt` anyway!?

Answer (score 9):

I realize that this is late, but I hope it helps.

In Azure, the linux agent configuration file (waagent.conf) usually sets the mountpoint and you do i from there for most Linux distros supported. You'll usually find the default mountpoint as "/mnt/resource"

In Ubuntu 16.04+ however, cloud-init overrides waagent.conf ephemeral0 mountpoint configuration as well as fstab on every deallocate/start.
Still, you can specify the mountpoint in a number of ways that will survive a reboot or deallocate/start. I'll discuss them below.

Now to answer your questions:

**question 1: should I just move my custom point outside of /mnt?**
I think you probably should if you're mounting stuff on /mnt as you probably don't want to mount stuff on a temp. disk unless you intend to do so.

**question 2: what's the cloud-init stuff doing anyway and can I get rid of it?**
I think you should not get rid of it. Instead, you can try to reconfigure the mountpoint the correct way.

**How to make it persist?**
Let's say you want to mount your Azure temp. disk on /mnt/resource.

Method 1 (clean): Create a new cloud-init conf. file in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d to define mountpoints:

```
    cat >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/91-azure_datasource.cfg <<EOF
mounts:
- [ ephemeral0, /mnt/resource ]
EOF
```

Method 2 (dirty): Remove cloud-init mount options from the temp. disk fstab entry to make it look like this:

```
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail       0       2
```

Method 3 (nasty): Look for the mountpoint line in cc_mounts.py, path: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_mounts.py` and change the mountpoint in the code. The line should look like:

```
defmnts = [["ephemeral0", "/mnt", "auto", defvals[3], "0", "2"],
           ["swap", "none", "swap", "sw", "0", "0"]]
```

Give it a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: with Method 1, I just notice it doesn't overwrite or replace but it add new line, example: 

<pre>
root@b1:~# cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/91_fstab.cfg
mounts:
    - [ /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1, /temp1, "ext4", "defaults", "0", "0"]
root@b1:~# grep Local /etc/fstab
/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1 /LocalDataDisk1 ext4 defaults,comment=cloudconfig 0 0
root@b1:~# mount | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1 on /temp1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /LocalDataDisk1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
<code>

Answer (score 0):

the easy workaround that I found,
it's just after edit the `/etc/fstab` file, set `chattr +i /etc/fstab`, in this way cloud-init is not able to overwrite it